# Will JavaScript in a PDF run an IOS WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, uiwebview

I have a PDF file that include JavaScript code for validation of the data entered in the PDF. This runs Adobe Reader. I would like to include the same functionality in my iPad App.

If I load this PDF in a UIWebView, will the JS code run or the JS runs only in Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute JavaScripts from within a PDF in UIWebView, but you might be able to implement those functions externally

Comment: What functionality do you have with JS in your PDF?

Comment: This company has a set of official application forms (forms that have  to follow a certain format due to governmental regulations) in which they have embedded JavaScript to validate the data entry. JavaScript in a PDF is an Adobe standard.These forms are currently used on WinPCs, they would like me to embed them in an iPad app so we do not have to redevelop the UI. I know it's a bad idea, but it's a client wish.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can fill PDF forms in UIWebView. Try loading the PDF in Mobile Safari

Answer (score 0):

The following might help if you just need a UI and you are willing to re-develop the validation logic. Mozilla's pdf.js has an example at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/acroforms that is using canvas to display the PDF content using HTML/JS and overlays HTML input elements. However there are no execution of the embedded in PDF JavaScript yet.

Comment: P.S. for Safari you may need to add compatibility.js